# How to get relative path using Groovy Gpath in json?

Tags: relative-path, rest-assured, rest-assured-jsonpath, jsonslurper, gpath

I am using rest assured with Serenity BDD and using Groovy Gpath to navigate thru JSON. Now, I have a scenario like where I need to get the Cost values more than 2 with below JSON. is there any way to use a relative path to navigate using GPath with JSON.

```
{
"Cadbury": {
    "Specs": {
        "Name": "5 Star",
        "Cost": "2.99"
    }
},
"Nestle": {
    "Specs": {
        "Name": "BarOne",
        "Cost": "1.99"
    }
},
"Arnotts": {
    "Specs": {
        "Name": "TimTam",
        "Cost": "4.99"
    }
},
"Milo": {
    "Specs": {
        "Name": "BarMilo",
        "Cost": "3.99"
    }
}
```

}

I have found that `depthFirst()` or ** and `breadthFirst()` or *  traversal can be used with XML but it didn't work with JSON.

Can someone please throw light on this..
Thanks

Comment: Is this the actual response or is this within an array ?

Comment: Hello, This is the actual response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It worked with below query,

```
collect{it.value.Specs}.findAll{it.Cost > '2.00'}.Cost
```